# npm ERR! missing script: deploy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, github-pages, package.json

I am deploying my application to github pages but when I run command `npm run deploy` but i get error

```
npm ERR! missing script: deploy

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\whoami\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-05T16_46_06_946Z-debug.log
```

I have defined deploy in my package.json file

```
...
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll --verbose --coverage --runInBand",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "predeploy":"npm run build",
    "deploy":"gh-pages -d build"
  }
...
```

Comment: Are you sure you run that command in the right directory?

Comment: oh yes, that was a problem, thanks :d

Answer (score 5):

make sure you have save package.json file. In my case i have not saved it so that is why error is coming

Answer (score 0):

Please check the terminal path. In my case, I forgot to change the directory inside my project.

Simply type the following:

```
cd *name-of-your-project*
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely didn't save the package.json file after editing it.

Answer (score -3):

Please close the current working terminal and open new terminal and try the command again.